# Jenkins marks build as failed, but tests are passed

Tags: javascript, jenkins

I have made a build with a parameters and build steps to use them over Windows batch command. After the build run in the console output I can see that the tests are passed and that the build step - run Windows batch has caused the failure. I am stuck and have no idea how to manage this. Some screenshots and Jenkins console output there.

Console output:

```
Started by user *********[enter image description here][1]
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Valiantsin2021/WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Valiantsin2021/WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.36.1.windows.1'
 > git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/Valiantsin2021/WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 141c7dd2e797548b9f294f211aa3a4d9529c0804 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 141c7dd2e797548b9f294f211aa3a4d9529c0804 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Initial commit"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk 141c7dd2e797548b9f294f211aa3a4d9529c0804 # timeout=10
[WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins5082752157245549591.bat

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task>npm install 
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

up to date, audited 480 packages in 3s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

14 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
[WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1749588332131908451.bat

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task>npx cross-env ENV=dev npm run wdio -- --suite smoke 
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> hardcore@1.0.0 wdio
> wdio run wdio.conf.js "--suite" "smoke"


Execution of 2 workers started at 2022-07-19T08:57:48.321Z

[1-0] RUNNING in firefox - C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\tests\SmokeCalculator.test.js
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\tests\SmokeCalculator.test.js
[0-0] Google
[0-0] YOPmail - РћРґРЅРѕСЂР°Р·РѕРІС‹Рµ, РђРЅРѕРЅРёРјРЅС‹Рµ Рё Р‘РµСЃРїР»Р°С‚РЅС‹Рµ Р°РґСЂРµСЃР° СЌР»РµРєС‚СЂРѕРЅРЅРѕР№ РїРѕС‡С‚С‹
[1-0] Google
[1-0] 
[0-0] PASSED in chrome - C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\tests\SmokeCalculator.test.js
[1-0] PASSED in firefox - C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\tests\SmokeCalculator.test.js
2022-07-19T08:58:15.829Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: Error in onCompleteHook: Error: Could not generate Allure report
    at Object.onComplete (C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\wdio.conf.js:335:29)
    at C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\utils.js:99:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at runOnCompleteHook (C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\utils.js:97:39)
    at Launcher.run (C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\launcher.js:96:75)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

 "spec" Reporter:
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 103.0.5060.114 windows #0-0] Running: chrome (v103.0.5060.114) on windows
[chrome 103.0.5060.114 windows #0-0] Session ID: fe8523ce66d5fa868d0b7d3137574262
[chrome 103.0.5060.114 windows #0-0]
[chrome 103.0.5060.114 windows #0-0] В» \tests\SmokeCalculator.test.js
[chrome 103.0.5060.114 windows #0-0] Smoke tests
[chrome 103.0.5060.114 windows #0-0]    [32mвњ“[39m Open google cloud calculator and yopmail.com
[chrome 103.0.5060.114 windows #0-0]
[chrome 103.0.5060.114 windows #0-0] [32m1 passing (10.3s)[39m
------------------------------------------------------------------
[firefox 102.0.1 windows #1-0] Running: firefox (v102.0.1) on windows
[firefox 102.0.1 windows #1-0] Session ID: e7b8f925-6948-4f01-8344-03170d54c237
[firefox 102.0.1 windows #1-0]
[firefox 102.0.1 windows #1-0] В» \tests\SmokeCalculator.test.js
[firefox 102.0.1 windows #1-0] Smoke tests
[firefox 102.0.1 windows #1-0]    [32mвњ“[39m Open google cloud calculator and yopmail.com
[firefox 102.0.1 windows #1-0]
[firefox 102.0.1 windows #1-0] [32m1 passing (11s)[39m


Spec Files:  2 passed, 2 total (100% completed) in 00:00:27 

Report successfully generated to allure-report
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
[WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task] $ C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\Allure\bin\allure.bat generate C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\allure-results -c -o C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\allure-report
Report successfully generated to C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\WebdriverIO-implementation-of-Hardcore-task\allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Recording test results
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
Finished: FAILURE
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMx50.png)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoWfa.png)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQyeM.png)

Comment: Although your tests passed I still see errors in the build. You need to fix those errors.  `Error in onCompleteHook: Error: Could not generate Allure report`

Comment: Yes, thank you, the allure report error was the cause.